# Need help for jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<body>
    <button> Change  </button>
    <div id="mydiv" style="margin:25% 0% 0% 37%">
        <a href="#" onclick="alert('buhaha');" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#99CC99; padding:10px; margin:5px">One</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="alert('buhaha');" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color: #FF9900;padding:10px; margin:5px"> Two</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click my "Change" button, onclick event must disable. After I click "Change" button again, onclick event must enable. How do I do these two actions from one button?

I used jquery-1.4.1.min.js. Answer code must work with jquery-1.4.1.min.js file.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What exactly is your problem?

Comment: hi felix , i sent email to ur gmail . can u check

Comment: So basically this is still related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062578/jquery-conflict-with-two-files)...

Comment: dear felix , i can not remove inline "onclick". because its need to my popup boxes .

Answer (score 0):

Delete the inline javascript `onclick="alert('buhaha');"`, then use:

```
$('button').toggle(function() {
  $('#mydiv > a').unbind('click');
}, function() {
  $('#mydiv > a').bind('click', function(){alert('buhaha')});
});
```

Comment: can not delete "onclick="alert('buhaha');" its need to my popups in my real project

Comment: @user1177842 without write `onclick="alert('buhaha');`, you can also popup what you want, can't you? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').toggle(function() {
  $('#mydiv a').unbind('click');
}, function() {
  $('#mydiv a').bind('click', doOnclick);
});

function doOnclick()
{
alert("hello");
}
```

Here you can call your inline javascript function in doOnclick function.